# Requisites for running c++ apps on Windows and Win XP targeting from VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have developed a Visual c++ app and now I'm working on its deployment. I've built the app using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate 64 bit an Windows 8 Pro 64 bit (yeah, got Win 8 Pro before launch, thanks to dreamspark). I want to know ALL the system requirements for running Visual C++ app on windows. I know that Visual c++ Redist and .NET framework are required.

Additionally, I came to know that apps built using VS 2012 do not run on Win XP and Win Server 2003. I spent some time on this but couldn't find proper help.

So I want to know prerequisites for running Visual C++ apps (on Win Xp, Vista, 7 and 8) and running Visual C++ apps on Win Xp built on VS 2012.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/10357555.aspx which allows you to build C++ apps for XP

Comment: I've already completed my app, so will installing the updates make the already built app work with XP or will I have to create a new project and copy the source code?

Comment: Okay, there's another problem, Visual C++ re-distributable  is required for running C++ apps built on VS. the version required for running VS 2012 c++ apps does not supports Win XP, so which version of Visual C++ re-dist do I need to install on Win XP?

Comment: Statically link the runtime. The link I provided tells you this. Please note it is only a preview. Maybe at a later date the full release of it will include redistributable runtimes.